# How to programmatically run arc diff --verbatim if test plan is required

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

We want to run arc diff using a jenkins job which will put out a diff programmatically.

We can use --verbatim option, but it's complaining about Invalid or missing field "Test Plan". We don't want to disable test plan requirement but arc diff doesn't seem to have an option to provide test plan from cli. So the question is how do we prevent arc diff prompt window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to have `arc diff --create --verbatim` to work, the last commit before you create the revision must have all the needed fields, eg. :

Title of commit

Summary: Summary of commit

Test Plan: A test plan

Say, if you want to do all of that programatically, you have to create this commit first.